# I want to fix my footer to the bottom of my content (not screen) so that it is all in one div ? Any ideas?

Tags: html, css, footer, fixed

I want to fix my footer at the bottom of my content so that when ever i add content it will just automatically adjust with it, Like this website here (http://www.matthamm.com/about)

Here is the Jsfiddle of what it more or less looks like now 
http://jsfiddle.net/9L6Lh/

HTML:
    
    Home

```
                <p>This Website will be made using PHP</p>
                <p>A Home Page</p>
                <p>A Style Sheet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer_wrapper">
    <div id="footer_inner_wrapper">
        <div>
            <p>&copy;
                <?php echo date( "Y"); ?>UR. All rights reserved. Andrew Byrne.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 10%;
min-width: 30%;
text-align: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image:url(/img/mooning.png);
font-weight:bold;
color:#666666;
}
#main {
height: auto;
width:80%;
margin:auto;
text-align:left;
padding:15px;
font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
background-color:red;
box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px #888;
overflow:auto;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}





.day3txt {
margin-top: 1%;
border-bottom: 3px solid #c7c7c7;
padding: 80px;
}
#footer_wrapper {
background-color: black;
}
#Contact-font li {
list-style: none;
}
#Contact-font li a {
border-bottom: 2px solid #336699;
}
#Contact-font li a:hover {
color: #E8110F;
opacity: 0.7;
}
/*banner */
#nav li {
margin-top: 0.25%;
white-space: nowrap;
list-style: none;
float:left
}
#nav li a {
font-size: 25px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #E8110F;
}
#nav select {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? Your fiddle does work. You just place a container after the content block? The Fiddle does what you want imo.

Comment: i want the footer to be connected to the main content, if you saw the sample site i gave, there's a little gap between it , when the screen re-sizes i would like the footer to re-size with the content but it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to the footer and append some margin.

here is your fiddle with "connected" footer: http://jsfiddle.net/9L6Lh/1/

```
#footer_wrapper {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this seems like it works, just that when i try to resize it to be the same as the main content it shifts off to the left and then when i resize the window it doesent move with the content but rather on its own , any thoughts ?

Comment: I did not see what you did to your main element. Here yo go: http://jsfiddle.net/9L6Lh/3/

Comment: Thank you so much Nico ! first question i've asked on SOF, always very skeptical about forums and asking questions ! i will be using them alot more now

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a paragraph inside the footer, the browser gave it some default style(There are default styles for every element). Use a CSS Reset like this:

```
*{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
 }
```

**OR**

Just add this to your style:

```
#footer_wrapper p{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a reset style sheet. All the other margins and paddings are OK. The only problem the OP has is the top margin on the p in the footer, so that's all it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add This only at the top in the css file so before body{}

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```